# Openstack Neutron on top of Amazon VPC

Tags: amazon-ec2, openstack, amazon-vpc, openstack-neutron

Is it possible to run Openstack Neutron within an Amazon VPC and still be able to use all of Neutron's features (GRE mesh network, etc)?

I do know about Amazon's ENI and networking tools within a VPC but they have limits that are too small for our application and seem to be strictly enforced (and can't be expanded).

Comment: What limits are a problem for you? AWS lets you request nearly any limit be raised, you just have to explain why. I've never had trouble and it usually happens within 24h.

Comment: The limits I would be running into are the limits on number of ENI interfaces per instance type and the number of IPs that can be associated with those interfaces. It didn't mention a way of requesting an increase for those

Comment: Larter instances have more ENIs. You might want to contact AWS Support and ask if they can help you with your use case.

Comment: If I may ask, why the downvote? So far, the original question remains unanswered and I think it is still a valid question that I have not been able to find an answer to online.

Comment: The downvote is not mine.

Answer (score 0):

Since nobody had any suggestions, I tested it out using Packstack on two CentOS instances within a VPC and was successfully able to have Neutron create GRE tunnels between compute nodes and was able to communicate over the tunnels between hosts.